# In C# why are my two objects not showing as equal?

Tags: c#

If I have this object

[image]

And then I try to compare it to this object

[image]

If I try to do a compare with .Equals it says these aren't equal

oma.Equals(cma)
false

Is it because of the Null value?

The class does not override equals.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Config_TestCases.Entities
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("BomComponents")]
    public class CustomBomComponent
    {
        [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
        public string ComponentName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
        public BomMaterialAttributes BomMaterialAttributes { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "BomMaterials", Order = 3)]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "BomMaterial")]
        public List<CustomBomMaterial> BOMMaterials { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "BomComponents", Order = 4)]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "BomComponent")]
        public List<CustomBomComponent> BomComponents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of those objects? Does it override `Equals`? That's not done automatically in C# unless you use records.

Comment: Much better than a picture would be a snippet of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I'm betting it's because `Equals` isn't overriden so you get the default `object` behaviour of comparing references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of `Equals` comes from `Object`, and there it works by comparing references, so it only returns true if both references point to *the exact same object*. So, your code works exactly as intended: they're not equal because they're different objects.

If that's not appropriate for your class, you'll have to override `Equals`. I suggest you follow [the official recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) for this.

Normally, I'd recommend to just use a `record`, which gets you automatically generated `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations, but since you have `List<T>` members, those will get reference equality because `record` just uses the default equality comparer for all members and `List<T>` doesn't override `Equals` either.

So looks like you'll have to override `Equals` the old fashioned way anyway and, as explained above, override `GetHashCode` too.